# Managing an Entity and its Snapshot with an ORM

Tags: entity-framework, design-patterns, ef-code-first, domain-driven-design

I would like to use one of the ideas that Jimmy Nilsson mentioned in his book [Applying DDD with Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268202), and that is if i have an entity like a ***Product*** for example, i would like to take a snapshot of that entity for historic information, something like ***ProductSnapshot*** but i wonder how i might be able to implement this with an ORM (i am currently using Entity Framework). The main problem i am facing is that if i have another Entity like ***OrderLine*** that receives the ***Product*** via its constructor then entity framework would need you to make a public property of the type you wish to persist so this will force me to have something like this:

```
class OrderLine {
public Product Original Product {get; set;}
public ProductSnapshot Snapshot {get; set;}
}
```

and that seems awkward and not intuitive and i don't know how to deal with it properly when it comes to data binding (to which property i should bind), and finally i think that ***Product*** is an **Entity** while ***ProductSnapshot*** is a **Value Object** plus the snapshot is only taken when the ***OrderLine*** is accepted and after that the ***Product*** is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing DDD, forget that the database exists. This means the ORM doesn't exist either. Now, because you don't have to care about persistence and ORM limits, you can model the ProductSnapshot according to the domain needs.

Create a ProductSnapshot class with all the required members.This class would be a result probably of a SnapshotService.GetSnapshot(Product p) . Once you have the ProductSnapshot just send it to a repository SnapshotsRepository.Save(snapshot) . Being a snapshot, this means it will probably be more of a data structure, a 'dumb' object. It also should be invariable, 'frozen' .

The Repository will use EF to actually save the data. You decide what the EF entities and relations are. ProductSnapshot is a considered to be a business object by the persistence(it doesn't matter if in reality it's just a simple Dto) and the EF entities may look very different (for example, I store business objects in serialized form in a key-value table) according to your querying needs.

Once you define the EF entites you need to map the ProductSnapshot to them. It's very probable that ProductSnapshot itself can be used as an EF Entity so you don't need to do any mapping.

The point is, that taking a snapshot seems to be domain behavior. You deal with the EF only after you have the snapshot and you do exactly as you'd do with any other busines object.

Comment: What do you think about the binding problem, cuz if i only have a property of type ProductSnapshot then that property would be null until the OrderLine is confirmed, and the same thing would happen if i have one property of type Product but in reverse situation ?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. The product snapshot is a business object which will be saved by a repository. The OrderLine class may contain a product snapshot, but that's not a EF issue. THe repository should know how to assemble the ORderLine with or without a Product or a Snapshot. The repository uses EF to get the relevant data, then it puts everything together. In a nutshell, keep the Domain and Persistence layers separate and don't mix the ORM when modelling business objects. ORM helps you work easier with the db, but the repository is responsible for dealing with the business objects.

Comment: You have to decide if the OrderLine, Product and ProductSnapshot here are the business objects or they are the EF entities which I hope aren't used to model the domain.

Comment: I get your point about the repository and i feel this is going to generate a long discussion and no i am not using EF entities to model the domain but i feel that you will always have to think a bit about the persistence framework you are using. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why does OrderLine have to have ProductSnapshot property? I suppose, you can either have a link to ProductSnapshot from Product class if you need to get that historical informatil, or, in case you just want to save Product state under some conditions, just implement a SaveSnapshot method in Product partial class, or have an extension method for it.